# Drupal Errors after Installation

Tags: 7, installation

I'm new to drupal, and just trying to get it up and running smoothly.

I installed it manually on my *Go Daddy* account, but I'm getting these errors when I click on the customization links at the top of the screen:
[image: Drupal error messages after installation - 1]
[image: Drupal error messages after installation - 2]

I can still do things (add content, etc.) but since I'm new, I have no idea if there is anything not being shown to me because of these errors. I just did a fresh install and I'm still having the same problems. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshots I could see that you are using acquia marina theme, and these errors are related to that theme.

Please make sure that, you installed/configured the theme properly.

Related issue in acquia marina theme issue queue - http://drupal.org/node/1057002

Comment: Ahh wow, thanks for that link. I didn't have one of the needed modules installed.